# SQL using UPDATE / CASE / WHEN

Tags: ms-access, sql-update

Looking to create an `Update` query that sets the values within a column based on the values of another column in the same table eg:

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET field1 = CASE field2
         WHEN field2 = 1 THEN "ASG1"
         WHEN field2 = 2 THEN "ASG2"
         WHEN field2 = 3 THEN "ASG3"
         WHEN field2 = 4 THEN "ASG4"
         WHEN field2 = 5 THEN "ASG5"
         ELSE Field1 (retaining old value)
         END
WHERE field2 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

Whatever I try I keep screwing up the statement

An example of data in current and then updated form would be:

```
field1 field2
value    1
value    2
value    3

field1 field2
asg1     1
asg2     2
asg3     3
```

Comment: `CASE field2  WHEN field2 = ...` is wrong. It's either `case field2 when 1 then ..` or `case when field2 = 1 then ...`. Please read the manual for your DBMS

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: This is for Access 2010 - Almost forgot ;)

Answer (score 4):

Access SQL does not support `CASE ... WHEN`.  You could use a `Switch` expression instead ...

```sql
UPDATE mytable
SET field1 = 
    Switch
        (
            field2 = 1, "ASG1",
            field2 = 2, "ASG2",
            field2 = 3, "ASG3",
            field2 = 4, "ASG4",
            field2 = 5, "ASG5"
        )
WHERE field2 IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

However, you could get your desired result with this simpler `UPDATE` ...

```sql
UPDATE mytable AS m
SET m.field1 = 'ASG' & [m].[field2]
WHERE m.field2 In (1,2,3,4,5);
```